# Python: Passing a list of IP addresses as a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, geolocation, ip-address

My code is designed to geo-locate IP addresses from a text file.  I'm having trouble on the last section.  When I run the code, I get a complaint from the map_ip.update line: `socket.error: illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton`

When I troubleshoot with a `print` statement, I get the following format:

```
['$ ip address']
['$ ip address']
['$ ip address']
```

How do I get `country_name_by_addr()` to read each IP address in the proper format?  It appears my IP addresses are being formatted as a list of strings in individual lists.

```
# script that geo-locates IP addresses from a consolidated dictionary

    import pygeoip
    import itertools
    import re

    # initialize dictionary for IP addresses
    count = {}

    """
    This loop reads text file line-by-line and
    returns one-to-one key:value pairs of IP addresses.
    """
    with open('$short_logins.txt path') as f:
      for cnt, line in enumerate(f):
        ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
        count.update({cnt: ip})
        cnt += 1

    """
    This line consolidates unique IP addresses.  Keys represent how 
    many times each unique IP address occurs in the text file.
    """
    con_count = [(k, len(list(v))) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(count.values)))]    


    """
    Country lookup:
    This section passes each unique IP address from con_count 
    through country name database.  These IP address are not required
    to come from con_count.
    """
    map_ip = {}
    gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('$GeoIP.dat path')

    for i in count.itervalues():
      map_ip.update({i: gi.country_name_by_addr(i)})

    print map_ip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this dilemma yesterday by doing away with the regular expression:

```
ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
```

I found a much simpler solution by stripping the whitespace in the file and checking to see if the IP address was accounted for.  IP addresses are all in the third column hence the [2]:

```
ip = line.split()[2]
if ip in count:
  count[ip] += 1
else:
  count.update({ip: 1})
```

I removed the con_count line as well.  Pygeoip functions are much more receptive to lists not made out of regular expressions.